# JS double mouseover

Tags: javascript, jquery, this, mouseover

I am trying to pass a custom attribute to a script. If I pass it this way:

```
$('a.load-local-image').cluetip( {
    local:true, 
    leftOffset: $("#par-1").attr("leftpos")
);
```

it works fine. However, I need to pass attribute of the current element, not just par-1. If I try it this way:

```
$('a.load-local-image').cluetip( {
    local:true, 
    leftOffset: $(this).attr("leftpos")
);
```

the function sees the parameter as not being passed at all. So, I tried wrapping the function in mouseenter():

```
$('a.load-local-image').mouseenter( {
    $(this).cluetip( {
        local:true, 
        leftOffset: $(this).attr("leftpos")
    });
});
```

which works fine except I have to mouseover *twice* before the cluetip script runs. I even tried preloading cluetip() this way:

```
$('a.load-local-image').cluetip();
$('a.load-local-image').mouseenter( {
    $(this).cluetip( {
        local:true, 
        leftOffset: $(this).attr("leftpos")
    });
});
```

and it still does the same thing. I also tried mouseover, mouseout, mouseleave, hover and every other mouse-related function I can think of.

For some inexplicable reason, the problem seems to be related to $(this). If I use anything except $(this) as a parameter, everything works fine. Unfortunately, the only way I pass the current element is $(this) unless someone has an idea how I can get it otherwise.

Here is the markup:

```
<div id="par-1">
    <a id="load-local" class="load-local-image featurelink" title="" href="" rel="#whatever" leftpos="220" toppos="48">
    <img src="images/image.jpg" alt="" class="featureimg"></a>
```

Any ideas on what is happening?

Answer (score 2):

passing `this` to cluetip will mean the global window object, not the current element. To get the current element, put it inside an `each` statement and initialize each cluetip one by one:

```
$('a.load-local-image').each(function () {
    var element = $(this);

    element.cluetip({
        local:true, 
        leftOffset: element.attr("leftpos")
    });
});
```